# How to inlcude Container Registry vulnerability scans in the CI/CD script using Cloud Build on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, continuous-deployment, google-container-registry, google-cloud-build

Is there a way to add the Container Registry vulnerability scans as a step in the .yaml script doing the CI/CD pipeline using Cloud Build. The idea will be to not deploy a image if the severity is critical or hight.

[image: using]

Right now the scan is done on Container Registry after an image is pushed but this is independant of the CI/CD pipeline script. I don't know what is the best practices in this area in particular in compagny that have heavy security rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now `GCP` is providing a "on demand scanning" functionality that can be used from a `Cloud Build` pipeline [link](https://cloud.google.com/container-analysis/docs/on-demand-scanning)

Right now the tool require 2-3 time the size of the container in RAM (Max with Cloud Build is 32 GB). I hope this will be improve soon. In such case we can use the --remote option, to scan a container already store in Artifac Registry

Answer (score 1):

My quick look right now suggests that the way to do it would be to have a step after your build & registry push steps that runs a vuln scan. Right now as it's in alpha the CLI doesn't have the get request you need, only the HTTP/Java & Go API's are currently developed.

As this sounds like its for work & this is still in very early pre-release I would suggest something like [Synk](https://snyk.io/) or [Anchore](https://anchore.com/) would be better alternatives as they are much more production ready.